# OSError: [Errno 98] Address 'hashserve.sock' is already in use"

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I really need help ..
I am using ubunto. I cloned poky the yocto project build system I have typed this command in the terminal "time bitbake core-image-minimal "and the download started it reach 40 % and my pc had shutdown I tried to restart the download by retyping the same command but I get this error "OSError: [Errno 98] Address 'hashserve.sock' is already in use"
I have tried to kill the process hashserve is using by this cmd "sudo kill -9 5128" it didn't work
can please help me

Answer (score 0):

I found the socket at `<work-dir>/tmp/hashserve.sock` and deleting it made BitBake work again using the same working directory.